# Decode generic type with Jackson

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, ktor

Jackson doesn't attempt to decode generic elements of a class.

How do you pass in the the type information without creating a specific version of the class?

The data types are:

```kotlin
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class HasuraTriggerPayload<T>(
    val event: HasuraEvent<T>,
    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    val createdAt: Instant,
    val trigger: Trigger
)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class HasuraEvent<T>(
    val op: String,
    val data: HasuraData<T>
)

data class HasuraData<T>(
    val old: T,
    val new: T
)

data class Trigger(
    val name: String
)

data class Price(
    val id: UUID,
    val price: BigDecimal?,
)
```

My route is something like:

```kotlin
post("/price") {
    val payload = call.receive<HasuraTriggerPayload<Price>>()
    // etc
}
```

Which produces this error because it doesn't know how to decode new/old:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.scraptickets.rest.models.Price (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.scraptickets.rest.models.Price is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

`trigger.name` gives the type. in this case, it's "price-trigger"

There are two possible solutions to this.

We know that T is Price at our particular call site, so we could somehow pass along that information, but how?

We can determine the type of `old` and `new` from `trigger.name`, but how do we write that? The only obvious way is from reading a field of the object we're trying to determine the class for, not from outside.

Comment: Generics only exist in your source code. When you run the application all generics are removed. You need to tell Jackson about your generic types and how to identify them.

Comment: Fair enough. How do I do that?

Comment: I've updated the data definition to include the trigger name. It looks like @JsonTypeInfo might be usable, but it's not obvious how to use it when it describes a type in a separate hierarchy in the data several levels down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of searching, I found the solution.

You need to create a `TypeReference`.

For my use the solution was:

```kotlin
post("/price") {
    val typeRef = object : TypeReference<HasuraTriggerPayload<Price>>() { }
    val objectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper() // Not quite this, I'm leaving out the part to handle timestamps
    val jsonStr = call.receiveText()
    val payload = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, typeRef)
    // etc
}
```